# Error accessing python-pptx picture placeholder after .insert_picture()

Tags: python, python-pptx

I use python-pptx to add a picture into a picture placeholder.
Then, I'd like to move the placeholder, but when I used something like placeholder.left, which is supposed to return the position of the left end of the placeholder, I get en error. When I do it just before adding the picture, it works fine....)
Here it is:

```
print("pic placeholder left - before inserting picture\n"+str(pic_placeholder.left))
print("\nListing plaseholders - before inserting picture")
for shape in ppt_slide.placeholders:
    print('%d----%s' % (shape.placeholder_format.idx, shape.name))
pic_placeholder = ppt_slide.placeholders[1]
picture = pic_placeholder.insert_picture(s.figures[0].file_name)
print("\nListing plaseholders - after inserting picture")
for shape in ppt_slide.placeholders:
    print('%d----%s' % (shape.placeholder_format.idx, shape.name))
print("pic placeholder left - after inserting 
picture\n"+str(pic_placeholder.left))
```

**And here's the output (look closely where it stops):**

```
2020-03-29 08:18:33 Listing plaseholders - before inserting picture
2020-03-29 08:18:33 
2020-03-29 08:18:33 0----Title 1
2020-03-29 08:18:33 1----Picture Placeholder 2
2020-03-29 08:18:33 2----Text Placeholder 3
2020-03-29 08:18:33 Listing plaseholders - after inserting picture
2020-03-29 08:18:33 
2020-03-29 08:18:33 0----Title 1
2020-03-29 08:18:33 1----Picture Placeholder 2
2020-03-29 08:18:33 2----Text Placeholder 3
```

**And here it crashes due to the error you are about to see in the error log:**

```
2020-03-29 08:18:33,171: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no
attribute 'x' 2020-03-29 08:18:33,171:   File
"/home/karrot/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py",
line 2463, in __call__ 2020-03-29 08:18:33,171:     return
self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response) 2020-03-29 08:18:33,171: 
2020-03-29 08:18:33,171:   File
"/home/karrot/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py",
line 2449, in wsgi_app 2020-03-29 08:18:33,171:     response =
self.handle_exception(e) 2020-03-29 08:18:33,172:  2020-03-29
08:18:33,172:   File
"/home/karrot/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py",
line 1866, in handle_exception 2020-03-29 08:18:33,172:    
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) 2020-03-29 08:18:33,172:  2020-03-29
08:18:33,172:   File
"/home/karrot/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py",
line 39, in reraise 2020-03-29 08:18:33,172:     raise value
2020-03-29 08:18:33,172:  2020-03-29 08:18:33,172:   File
"/home/karrot/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py",
line 2446, in wsgi_app 2020-03-29 08:18:33,172:     response =
self.full_dispatch_request() 2020-03-29 08:18:33,172:  2020-03-29
08:18:33,172:   File
"/home/karrot/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py",
line 1951, in full_dispatch_request 2020-03-29 08:18:33,172:     rv =
self.handle_user_exception(e) 2020-03-29 08:18:33,173:  2020-03-29
08:18:33,173:   File
"/home/karrot/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py",
line 1820, in handle_user_exception 2020-03-29 08:18:33,173:  
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb) 2020-03-29 08:18:33,173:  2020-03-29
08:18:33,173:   File
"/home/karrot/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/_compat.py",
line 39, in reraise 2020-03-29 08:18:33,173:     raise value
2020-03-29 08:18:33,173:  2020-03-29 08:18:33,173:   File
"/home/karrot/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py",
line 1949, in full_dispatch_request 2020-03-29 08:18:33,173:     rv =
self.dispatch_request() 2020-03-29 08:18:33,173:  2020-03-29
08:18:33,173:   File
"/home/karrot/.virtualenvs/my-virtualenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/flask/app.py",
line 1935, in dispatch_request 2020-03-29 08:18:33,173:     return
self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args) 2020-03-29
08:18:33,173:  2020-03-29 08:18:33,174:   File
"/home/karrot/mysite/flask_app.py", line 26, in index 2020-03-29
08:18:33,174:     rpg.PG03m(str(pippo[0])) 2020-03-29 08:18:33,174: 
2020-03-29 08:18:33,174:   File
"/home/karrot/mysite/PresentationGenerator09min_method.py", line 324,
in PG03m 2020-03-29 08:18:33,174:     temp_ppt=P1.make_ppt()
2020-03-29 08:18:33,174:  2020-03-29 08:18:33,174:   File
"/home/karrot/mysite/PresentationGenerator09min_method.py", line 229,
in make_ppt
```

Thank in advance and take care!!! Corona is out there!
JT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting a picture into a picture-placeholder actually deletes the placeholder shape and inserts a picture shape. This is also the way PowerPoint itself does it; a placeholder shape is a `<p:sp>` element whereas a picture is a `<p:pic>` element.

So you should either do the moving beforehand, using the placeholder, or use the reference to the newly inserted picture shape returned by `PicturePlaceholder.insert_picture()` to manipulate the new shape after insertion.

```
picture = pic_placeholder.insert_picture(s.figures[0].file_name)
print("picture left - after inserting picture\n%s" % picture.left)
```

Comment: This works, thanks @scanny ! I mean, I can access the variable pic.left, but when I try to change it, the picture disappears! when I write something like `picture.left=Cm(5)` and open the resulting pptx file, I can't find the picture! it happens for Cm, Inches, Pt with no matter the argument. How do I tackle this? Thanks!